# The proof of cartan's magic formula

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to use integral to prove the cartan's magic formula, i.e., it's enough to prove that for all small disk $D$ of dim=k=deg $\alpha$ in a manifold $M$, we have 
$$
\int_D L_X\alpha = \int_D (d(i_X\alpha)+i_X d\alpha.
$$
To prove that, we consider a flow of X $\phi: D\times [0,\epsilon]\to M$, then 
$$
\int_D L_X\alpha= \int_D \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\phi^*_t\alpha=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}(1/\epsilon)\int_D(\phi^*_{\epsilon}\alpha-\alpha).
$$
What can we do to continue?

Comment: Hint: Try to use Stokes's Theorem on $D\times [0,\epsilon]$ to compute that derivative by the definition.